# How to choose xpath return type?

Tags: xslt, xpath, documentfragment

I have the xpath query:

```
        <xsl:variable name="fbids">
            <xsl:sequence select="
                feature_relationship[type_id/cvterm[name='molec_deletes' or name='deletes']]
                /object_id/feature/feature_synonym/synonym_id/synonym/synonym_sgml"/>
        </xsl:variable>
```

This query does not return a sequence of matching nodes as a sequence itself, it returns them as children of a single #documentfragment.  Even if no elements satisfy this query, $fbids is still set to an empty #documentfragment.

This screws up my code whereas the following loop, instead of iterating once per matched element, runs once through for the #documentfragment and that's it.  How can I force this to return a nice element()* type?

Thanks!

Comment: XSLT 1 or 2? There is a big difference in this general area. Oh, and wouldn't simply `<xsl:variable name="fbids" select="..."/>` do the job?

Comment: XSLT 2, and yes it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>       <xsl:variable name="fbids">
>           <xsl:sequence select="
>               feature_relationship[type_id/cvterm[name='molec_deletes' or name='deletes']]
>               /object_id/feature/feature_synonym/synonym_id/synonym/synonym_sgml"/>
>       </xsl:variable>
> ```
>
> This query does not return a sequence of matching nodes as a sequence
>   itself, it returns them as children of a single #documentfragment.

Yes, because there is a sequence inside the body of the variable and the variable has no type specified. The default type in such case is: `document-node()`.

**Solution**:

Specify the variable without a body and provide the XPath expression in the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable`:

```
<xsl:variable name="fbids" select="
  feature_relationship[type_id/cvterm[name='molec_deletes' or name='deletes']]
    /object_id/feature/feature_synonym/synonym_id/synonym/synonym_sgml"/>
```

It is still a good practice to specify the wanted type of the variable using the `as` attribute.

**A complete answer also must cover the case** when the value of the variable (a sequence of elements) is dynamically created inside its body.

**Again specifying the type of the variable is key to the solution**.

Here is a small and complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">

  <xsl:variable name="vMapped" as="element()*">
    <xsl:for-each select="num">
      <num><xsl:value-of select=".*2"/></num>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vMapped">
   <xsl:sequence select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

the variable named `$vMapped` gets its dynamically created value inside its body. The rest of the code successfully uses this variable as a sequence of elements -- each of the elements in this sequence is accessed and copied to the output:

```
<num>2</num>
<num>4</num>
<num>6</num>
<num>8</num>
<num>10</num>
<num>12</num>
<num>14</num>
<num>16</num>
<num>18</num>
<num>20</num>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default type for a variable in XSLT 2.0 is a documentfragment. If you want it to be a sequence of elements, then add the `as` attribute and specify the sequence type. You can also use the `select` attribute, rather than nested sequence element:

```
<xsl:variable name="fbids" as="element()*" select="
            feature_relationship[type_id/cvterm[name='molec_deletes' or name='deletes']]
             /object_id/feature/feature_synonym/synonym_id/synonym/synonym_sgml"/>
```